# C++: Change value of variable using its pointer

Tags: c++, pointers

Let's say I have the following funciton:

```
void part(T* arr){
//some function
int x[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
arr = x;
}
```

where original:

```
int arr[5] = {0,0,0,0,0}
```

I would like to know, how can I change the value of original `arr` inside the function to be some other value (lets say `x`)?

Thanks

Comment: You can't reassign arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this, you would need to copy elements from the array `x` to `arr`:

```
std::copy(x, x + sizeof(x) / sizeof(x[0]), arr);
```

However, as a general advice, don't use raw pointers to represent an array of objects. You could use `std::array` instead and then you can use it's `operator=` to copy all elements.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

void part(std::array<int, 5>& arr)
{
    std::array<int, 5> x {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}};
    arr = x;
}

int main()
{
    std::array<int, 5> arr;

    part(arr);

    for (const auto& val : arr) {
        std::cout << val << " ";
    }

}
```

[LIVE](http://rextester.com/EAFI32481)

Answer (score 2):

You were close.

```
void part(T* arr){
   //some function
   int x = 5;
   *arr = x;
}
```

You just need to add a * in front of arr which means the value pointed to by that pointer.  If you just say arr that means the actual address which you do not want to be changing.

Looks like you changed the question while I was writing my answer.

In this case you need a loop.

```
void part(T* arr){
   //some function
   int x[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
   for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
   {
      arr[i] = x[i];
   }
}
```

Comment: Hey @chasep255, I've added additional info about my data structue. These are an arrays of ints

Comment: Is there a way to do this without the loop?

Comment: You could look into the memset or std::copy function but you can't do it with a trivial assignment.  Actually you can if you store the array in a vector.